# java check values

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to search if char from alpabet array is equal to the textCharArray's element. And if so do some math: char number from alphabet to add to arrayList value. But I getting an error:

**java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

The problem should be in for cicles. But I don't know how to fix it corectly.
The 
Code:

```
                outputText.setText("");
            inputTextString = inputText.getText().toString().replace(" ", ""); //panaikinami tarpa
            char[] textCharArray = inputTextString.toCharArray(); //seka paverciama char masyvu
            int l = textCharArray.length;
            char[] alphabet = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','V','X','Y','Z'};
            int alpLenght = alphabet.length;
            System.out.println(alpLenght);
            stringKey = inputKey.getText().toString();
            int k = Integer.parseInt(stringKey);
            List<Integer>keyList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            while(k > 0){
                keyList.add(k%10);
                k = k /10;
            }
            Collections.reverse(keyList);
            int j = 0;
            int temp;
            for(int i = 0; i <= l; i++){
                for(int ii = 0; ii < alpLenght; i++){
                    if(j < keyList.size()){
                        if(textCharArray[i] == alphabet[ii]){
                            temp = ii + keyList.get(j);
                            System.out.println("Uzkoduotas: " + temp);
                            }
                        j++;
                    }



                else {
                    j = 0;
                        if(textCharArray[i] == alphabet[ii]){
                            temp = ii + keyList.get(j);
                            System.out.println("Uzkoduotas: " + temp);
                        }
                    }
                    j++;
                }
```

Comment: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question (once you've narrowed it down to a 10-line [test-case](http://sscce.org)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error here

```
      for(int i = 0; i <= l; i++){
            for(int ii = 0; ii < alpLenght; i++){
                if(j < keyList.size()){
                    if(textCharArray[i] == alphabet[ii]){
                        temp = ii + keyList.get(j);
                        System.out.println("Uzkoduotas: " + temp);
                        }
                    j++;
                }
```

You have and infinite loop because of the faulty for, and the i is being incremented until he is out of bounds.

You use **ii** variable but you increment **i** in this line:

```
   for(int ii = 0; ii < alpLenght; i++){
```

Replace with

```
   for(int ii = 0; ii < alpLenght; ii++){
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
  for(int i = 0; i < l; i++)<------Remove =
```

**instead of**

```
   for(int i = 0; i<=l; i++)
```

`Last index of array is array.size()-1`  and you try to get `array.size()`

so ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException...